# Startex align with column

Tags: multicol

**Original:**
[image]

**I want it like this: How can i do it?**

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.7pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.2cm}

\newcommand{\Startex}[1]{%
\noindent
\parbox[t]{\columnwidth}{%
    \vspace*{0.9cm}
    \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}
    \textbf{Q.1.}
     
#1}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}

    \Startex{
       text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
       }
       
\end{multicols*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not using a list of LaTeX? With the package `enumitem`, it's easy to customize the LaTeX lists such as `{enumerate}` of `{itemize}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{multicol}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{1.7pt}
\setlength{\columnsep}{1.2cm}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{multicols*}{2}
\vspace*{9mm}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{Q.\arabic*.}]
\item text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]